# How to get the value of array inside another array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$vars = Array (
[name] => youname
[fields] => Array
        (
            [field_52aab3d95f535] => 400
            [field_52d5e94738a5a] => 
            [field_52aab3e65f536] => 
            [field_52aab3f85f537] => In Progress
            [field_52aab40e5f538] => 1
            [field_52aab3548adfc] => 
        )
)
```

Given this, how do I target "In Progress"? For the name, I can use $vars['name'], but I have trouble getting the values inside another array.

Comment: How about just $vars['fields']['field_52aab3f85f537']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do:

```
$vars['fields']['field_52aab3f85f537'];
```

In this way you access the value directly.

See also the docs: [PHP arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You access them as array's value - array. If that makes sense, not to me atm. HEHEHE

```
echo $vars['fieids']['field_52aab3d95f535'];
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) will help you to print the values of array inside another array.

```
foreach($vars['fields'] as $fields => $value){
    echo $array[$fields];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
echo $vars['fieids']['field_52aab3d95f535'];